# I am unable to use the Algolia widgets

Tags: reactjs, algolia

Am using Algolia on my React App to do an instant search It works fine to get the Hits and results,
but to make it a more friendly user experience by adding the Sort-By(price: asc or desc) its doesn't work, I used the Sort-By component provided by Algolia.

Here is the code:

```
function Search() {

  const searchClient = algoliasearch('C*********X', 'd***************************9');

  const Hit = ({hit}) =>  {
   return <div>
    <h2>{hit.ProductName}</h2>
    <h3>{hit.ProductPrice}</h3>
  </div>
  }


  return (
    <div>
  <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="Products">
    <SearchBox />
    <Hits hitComponent={Hit}/>
  </InstantSearch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This works fine but when I add the Sort-by component Like

```
<div>
  <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="Products">
    <SearchBox />
<SortBy
  defaultRefinement="Products"
  items={[
    { value: 'relevent', label: 'Relevent' },
    { value: 'product_price_asc', label: 'Price asc.' },
    { value: 'product_price_desc', label: 'Price desc.' },
  ]}
/>
    <Hits hitComponent={Hit}/>
  </InstantSearch>
    </div>
```

The Sort-By Select Shows up by when I change it nothing happens, Is there an easy way to implement the Algolia widgets Ive been stuck on this for days now please help.

Answer (score 1):

The sortBy widget simply swaps between Algolia indices. The actual sorting occurs within your index and its replicas based on their sorting/ranking criteria. The widget in your code is swapping between three indices/replicas:

- relevent
- product_price_asc
- product_price_desc

Can you confirm all three indices/replicas exist and are accessible with your current search-only API key?